How to design the animation system for part-customizable robot in Unity?
I'm using Unity to build a game, where players can customize their robots with different parts of a variety of sizes and lenghts.
For example, players can put a pair of very long legs with an average body together. There're also multiple types of legs, e.g., two legs, four legs, or wheels, so the animation will be very different.
I'd like to have some idea how to implement this, since there's no single animation fits all.

Is there any native feature/support for this scenarios in Unity?
Any industrial best practice for it?
If no, how to do it? Add bones for all the parts, then design actions for similar bones, and play animations for all the parts together? E.g., when the robot is walking, play the walking animation for the legs, the body, the arms, and the heads at the same time? In this case, how to make sure parts are connected together when moving?


In your research, have you reviewed write-ups and developer talks about how the procedural animation was done for player-created creatures in Spore? This may have some useful inspirations, even if your setup is different from theirs. You may also want to look at the Animation Rigging package for Unity.
